# How to use npm package: axios in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

I want to do AJAX Request with Axios in Laravel. I did `npm install axios --save` but i don't know how to use it. Please help me how can I use axios in my laravel project.

Here's my ajax-land.blade.php:

```
<div id="app">
    <ul>
        <li v-for = "skill in skills" v-text = "skill"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src = "https://vuejs.org/js/vue.js"></script>
<script src = "/js/axisa.js"></script>
```

Here's my axisa.js:

```
 new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        skills: []
    },
    mounted(){
        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: '/links'
        })
        .then(response => this.skills = response.data)
    }
});
```

Here are my routes:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('ajax-land');
});

Route::get('/links', function(){
    return ['Google', 'Microsoft', 'Facebook', 'Twitter', 'LinkedIn'];
});
```

Here's the bootstrap.js:

```
window._ = require('lodash');

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap-sass');
} catch (e) {}

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Next we will register the CSRF Token as a common header with Axios so that
 * all outgoing HTTP requests automatically have it attached. This is just
 * a simple convenience so we don't have to attach every token manually.
 */

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

// import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

// window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

// window.Echo = new Echo({
//     broadcaster: 'pusher',
//     key: 'your-pusher-key'
// });
```

Here's the app.js:

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

There were some tutorials to import axios in bootstrap.js by `import axios from 'axios';` - and also did `window.axios = axios` in axisa.js but for some reason it didn't work. Please help me how can i use axios in Laravel.

Comment: Laravel comes with Axios already configured for you. What do your app.js and boostrap.js files look like?

Comment: And what is this axisa.js file? Why does it exist? Did you create it yourself?

Comment: Yes @NathanHeffley in `public/js/`

Comment: Is it replacing your normal app.js file? Why did you delete the perfectly configured default Laravel axios and Vue stuff?

Comment: Yup! Like that.

Comment: Could you try creating a new Laravel installation and just copying the axios code from the app.js and bootstrap.js files and using that? It works perfectly out of the box. I don't know why you would delete it and you haven't explained.

Comment: Yeah, Laravel sets this all up ready-to-go. Put it back and it'll work just fine.

Comment: You can add add axios like this: ```let axios = require('axios');```, right above your ```Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));``` in ```app.js```. Where is your ```vue``` file? Where is this ```axisa.js``` located in your directory? You should have a ```resources/assets/js/components``` directory with a ```vue``` inside of it where you can implement ```axios``` but I have no clue what your app is supposed to do.

Answer (score 3):

Axios is a simple promise based HTTP client. In Laravel, it is on the window object by default, so just use like so:

**GET**

```
axios.get('/some-path').then(res => {
    console.log(res.data)
})
```

**POST**

```
let data = {
    some: "thing"
}
axios.post('/some-path', data).then(res => {
    console.log(res.data)
})
```

[Documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios) is pretty good, as always, RTFM.

---

**EDIT 1**

If you get undefined on the axios object, use

```
import axios from 'axios'
```

at the top of your JS file and if you are entirely missing Axios, `npm install axios --save`

Comment: It says Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: axios is not defined" when i do the thing in axisa.js! Should i do this in app.js and then compile with laravel mix?

Comment: It says `Unexpected Token import`

Comment: @Sanjay Have you imported/required **bootstrap.js** in your **axisa.js**?

Answer (score 1):

in your resource/assests/js/app.js

simple add:
var axios = require('axios');

since
import axios from 'axios'
- seems to be depricated