# problem with using axios in Laravel 8 | axios is not defined

Tags: axios

hello everyone for a realtime laravel application i want to use axios . in app.js file in resources directory I required axios file here is all app.js file codes :

```
require('./bootstrap');
window._ = require('lodash');
window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

the problem is when I want to use axios in frontend it errors that axios is not defined so what the problem ? can someone help me please ...

Comment: How are you using *axios* on the front end?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use npm package: axios in Laravel 5.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47160473/how-to-use-npm-package-axios-in-laravel-5-5)

Answer (score 0):

i realized that in my layout template I forgot delete defer from app.js script and it cause in entire project Axios and Echo libraries not be recognized so after deleted "defer" from script tag it works like a charm